# Tar permissions transfer across machines

Tags: permissions, tar

I have files/folders on **Server A**, and the users that own them are `root` and `user1`. If I pack them into a tar file and move them to **Server B**, will those permissions transfer correctly to **Server B** if I have two users named `root` and `user1` on that server as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if `Server A : root` and `Server B : root`, and `Server A : user1` and `Server B : user1` have the same `UID`s (the 3rd field in the `/etc/passwd` entry)

`tar` does **NOT** store the username, just the `UID`. `UID`s are converted to usernames locally, for the convenience of humans.